# Firing an activity on receipt of some file over bluetooth

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible in android to start an activity on receiving a file over bluetooth? I do not have a bluetooth connection established inside the application. I wish to know if a user externally accepts a file, could my application register this event and start an activity. Maybe by checking for a specific file name in a known path.

I have looked into passing intents of various kinds to even start activities residing in other applications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think it can be done with BroadcastReceiver and BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult

But PendingResult is available only in honeycomb(int version 11).

Comment: Well I figured out this could be done using AsyncTask Class. Thanks anyways.